# WebView rendering very slow in Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, webview

In my app I have a section that displays forum posts. All forum posts are HTML and I display 20 per page. I'm using a ScrollView with 20 WebViews. One of the features is that when a user opens a forum thread, I load all the WebViews and scroll to the last post the user has read. Since it is not very easy know when the forum posts are fully rendered, I just postDelay the scrolling for 200ms.

Everything worked fine until Android 4.4 KitKat came out with the new Chromium based WebView.

The rendering is so slow that the 200ms expire, I scroll to the correct WebView and the rendering only happens after a few seconds after scrolling. Which means that the position of the WebView the user should see will go off the screen because the sizes of the WebViews have changed.

What would be a workaround for this problem since postDelaying for 5 seconds is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: Using 20 WebViews to display forum posts seems excessive. Does reducing the number help? Could you not just use 1 WebView? Other than that it's hard to diagnose your perf problem without more info - could you provide a link to your app?

Comment: The app has always used 20 webviews because the server sends the HTML for each post separately. The app is AndroidPIT, you can search it on the Play Store. I don't want to post a link to avoid being called a spammer (happened before). Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a ListView rather then put all of the WebView's on the page at once? Using the convert view in a ListView adapter  should mean you cut down the number of webviews quite a bit and hopefully that will give you better performance. Beyond that, have you tried using onPageFinished to see when each page is loaded rather than wait 200ms to then scroll?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a ListView with a convert view but it doesn't work because I can't scroll to a view that hasn't been rendered yet. So, if I know that I need to scroll to position 15, I scroll there and then the adapter returns the WebView and renders it, which changes the scrolling position after the render. I'm using onPageFinished and I count how many onPageFinished have happened. Once the last onPageFinish finishes, I wait 200ms and then scroll. I think I'll have to track the size of the WebView and track onSizeChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I took a look at your app and your problem is not rendering performance but page load time/time to layout.

It is possible that the delay between the `onPageFinished` event and the WebView performing layout has changed between WebView versions but from a trivial A/B comparison (at least on 1st-gen Nexus 7) it doesn't look like the time to load the contents has increased significantly (that is it seems to take about the same amount of time to load all of the forum posts both on Classic and Chromium WebView).

The `onPageFinished` callback only means that the main resource for the main frame had been successfully *loaded*. It doesn't mean that the data from the resource has been displayed on screen.

Waiting for a >0 height in `onSizeChanged` seems like reasonable approach. It will fail if the posts contain resources that are slow to load (like a big image) but waiting till all the posts fully load mean that you might end up having to wait a long time.